# Swift - app that requires communication between phones on different networks

Tags: ios, swift, communication

I'm just starting iOS app development with Swift (and in general) and I'm looking to get some information on popular practices when creating apps that require communication over arbitrary networks (i.e. not necessarily on the same network). I tried searching this on google but the answers weren't entirely what I was looking for; hopefully somebody can point be in the right direction. I wouldn't mind paying for a service, but unfortunately I don't know the first thing about backends and don't want to end up overpaying for services that I don't need. For example, I found an API called Parse, but I think it has far too many features that wouldn't benefit my app. Here's the main premise of the app:

1. There are two versions of the app - one for Admins and one for Employees
2. The Admins have the ability to post notes to a central list of notes for the employees to see
3. The Employees can access this list and scroll through it to pick which one they want to open. After a certain number of time, the notes expire and are removed from the list automatically

It's as simple as that. There likely won't be too many notes getting sent at once, so a large database isn't needed. My questions are as follows:

- Do I need a database to store the notes, or can I handle it in some other way?
- How is communication generally handled? The only things I've come across are ways to communicate when you're on the same WiFi or Bluetooth, but I haven't seen anything outside of that. How does an app like GroupMe communicate to users?
- This is more of a general question, but how can you tell if you need a backend or not? I'm still kinda confused on the interaction between the frontend and backend.

Any help for any of the questions is greatly appreciated. I feel as though I don't even know where to start with a project like this.

EDIT: To clarify, I'm just looking for a place to start, not code or any implementation.

Comment: Check out parse's SDK for iOS. You can store data on their website for free and call it from your app. This will mean you don't have to make your own http requests. On Udemy Rob Percival has a great course that shows you how to use parse in iOS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> It's as simple as that. There likely won't be too many notes getting sent at once, so a large database isn't needed. My questions are as follows:
>
> Do I need a database to store the notes, or can I handle it in some other way?

Yes you need some kind of database. That could be something complex like MySQL or something simple like writing a txt file for each note to the disk, with the filename being the date of the note.

You could use a service like Parse or run your own PHP server and write the software yourself. Parse is cheaper for a small database, running your own PHP server is cheaper for a big one and it gives you more control.

(You don't have to use PHP, but that is the most popular language for these things and it's what I use).

> How is communication generally handled? The only things I've come across are ways to communicate when you're on the same WiFi or Bluetooth, but I haven't seen anything outside of that. How does an app like GroupMe communicate to users?

Usually your the phone sends a HTTP POST request to the server with some text in JSON format in the body of the HTTP request.

The server then responds with more text in JSON format in the response.

On the phone you use NSURLSession to handle to do the network communication and NSJSONSerialization to encode/decode the content. On the server, there will be something equivalent available.

Usually there would be a username and password or some other authentication system in the HTTP POST JSON text that tells the server wether or not the user is allowed to do whatever they're trying to do.

All communication between the phone and the server must be encrypted using SSL to protect your users. Do your homework and make sure you get this part right before you deploy your app to the store.

Parse will handle all of that stuff for you, but it's good to at least understand what's going on.

> This is more of a general question, but how can you tell if you need a backend or not? I'm still kinda confused on the interaction between the frontend and backend.

You know you need a backend if you want two devices to communicate without being on the same WiFi/Bluetooth network. This is a security feature that cell network carriers (and home broadband ISPs) enforce to prevent malicious activity.

Generally only a commercial internet connection (and commercial router) will allow anonymous incoming network packets to get through to a phone/computer connected via that internet connection. Consumer internet connections only allow traffic coming in from a known source (for example, if you ask Google for some data, the router will temporarily allow Google to send some data to you. But if Google just sends some data without a phone/computer in your home asking for it, then it will be rejected).

You should be able to take what I've written and do a bunch of research.

If you decide to go with writing your own system in PHP, it comes pre-installed with OS X (just has to be enabled) and you can access it by IP address from the phone as long as you're on the same IP address. That should get you started for testing/development purposes at least.

The only part you won't have is SSL. Starting in iOS 9 (it's almost here!) you will need to disable NSURLSession's built in check for SSL or else it won't let you connect to the test server.